# Is it possible to use CSS custom properties with LESS functions?

Tags: css, less, css-variables

I'd like to be able to use LESS's darken function with a CSS custom property. I had something like this in mind:

```
:root {
  --color-primary: green;
}

div {
  background-color: darken(var(--color-primary), 50%);
}
```

But this gives me an error. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: In short, no - Less does not support CSS vars (except passing them as they are). So in this case the only way to achieve what you want is to define a corresponding Less variable.

Comment: Thank you, that's what i assumed...

Comment: I just found a workaround in that [Github issue](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2986#issuecomment-520704830) that works for me. Last comment says that with Less 3.x it should also works without the workaround.